# How define custom DNS server for QEMU VM via CLI?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, dns, qemu

How define custom DNS server for QEMU VM via CLI?
I want only for that virtual machine dns at `192.168.1.51` which is `pi-hole`.

`sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -gtk -m 1G -hda "ubuntu22.qcow2" -cpu host --enable-kvm -smp 1`is there any command argument for custom dns?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Apparently you'll need to use `-nic bridge,br=some_bridge` with the `some_bridge` being an "internal" bridge (NO host-side NIC is enslaved to it), then you enable IP (not port) forwarding and NAT on the host, and set up dnsmasq as the DHCP server (where you can specify a DNS server address to give out to the client / VM). Apparently `-nic user,dns=some_dns_address` will NOT work as you want / expect. (I'm not sure what it does behind the scene or why it does that but apparently something quirky.)

Comment: Or just change the DNS server to use on the guest side.